# How to use bookmarks as shorthand for URLs?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarks

Suppose there's an URL which I've bookmarked. I can access it as a bookmark **but** I'd like to be able to simply type in the name of the bookmark on the URL like (you know, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>) and have FF take me there.

I've tried doing that in my FF (latest version) but I don't get it to work. Instead, it googles for the word I'm specifying (which is a great feature too but as a secondary choice of action, i.e. when there's no bookmarks with to be found).

How can I do that? Can I do that?

## edit

It's possible that I'm going about it in a totally wrong way. When I press the shortcut above, I get the following appearance from my foxy. That differs from the image in the answer by @screener...

[image]

Comment: @Ramhound what are you talking about? That's a default feature of Firefox, as you can see in my answer.

Comment: @screener - I assume a certain level of research the author has done before asking a question.  So my comment was based on the fact, they found no such feature, and thus was asking what their options were.

Comment: @Ramhound It seems that some part of the conversation is removed. I only see screener's comments. What's been said? Also, as you can see the edition, perhaps that'll shed some more clarity on my issue?

Comment: @KonradViltersten he had told you to write an extension to solve your simple problem, as if Firefox didn't include that option by default. Also, I've told you to open the **Firefox Library**, not to click on the bookmark star. I've changed the order of my screenshots to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bookmark already exists, open the Firefox Library (a way to do that is to type `chrome://browser/content/places/places.xul` in your address bar), click on your bookmark and then use these fields to edit it:

[image: Editing a Firefox bookmark]

Once in the Firefox Library, you can create more bookmarks with keywords:

[image: Firefox bookmark keyword]

You can also use this feature to [create keyword searches](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_keyword_searches) with a `%s` parameter. For example, if you create a bookmark pointing to `https://example.org/%s` with the keyword `showme`, and then type `showme Tokyo` in your address bar, it will take you to `https://example.org/Tokyo`.  This can be used to create custom searches and quick shorcuts for many useful things, like dictionaries, maps, price comparison tools etc.

Firefox will create such a custom search for you automatically if you right-click on a search bar and pick the "Add a Keyword for this Search" option: [How to search IMDB, Wikipedia and more from the address bar](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/how-search-from-address-bar).

Comment: Please see the edit in my question. I have no such moreish-thingy on my foxy. Or am I going blind/retarded?! I quadruple-chekced that I've got the latest version...

Comment: @KonradViltersten The thing in your edit is the bookmark star/quick bookmark popup. You must open the **Firefox Library** (chrome://browser/content/places/places.xul).

Comment: Is it only me who finds it weird that it says **chrome** in your URL for accessing settings in **FireFox**?!

Comment: @KonradViltersten It was the terminology used by Mozilla that actually inspired Google to use that name. See https://www.quora.com/How-did-Google-come-up-with-the-Chrome-brand/answer/Glen-Murphy